About divorce and nikah
I am girl i married a guy who converted muslim to marry me he was just showing he is muslim just to marry me but later I found that he is not muslim he just showed to be muslim just to marry me and he said that to me he don't  believe in religion.so in that case I am still in nikah with him or not and in document I am still his wife in that case can I have nikah with other person or I need written divorce contract to marry other guy
